# Can I use multiple nibs files with the same owner class **at the same time**?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nib

Can I load multiple nibs files with the same owner class **at the same time** ?

So I can load sheets from different nibs ?

I'm currently using NSBundle:

```
[NSBundle loadNibNamed:@"nib1" owner:self];
[NSBundle loadNibNamed:@"nib2" owner:self];
```

But I get this error message"

```
<Error>: kCGErrorIllegalArgument: _CGSFindSharedWindow: WID 3387
<Error>: kCGErrorFailure: Set a breakpoint @ CGErrorBreakpoint() to catch errors as they are logged.
<Error>: kCGErrorIllegalArgument: CGSOrderWindowListWithGroups: invalid window ID (3387)
```

thanks

Comment: Why you don't load 2 different views, one for each nib, and the add/remove them (or bring back/forward) when you need?

Comment: @il Malvagio Dottor Prosciutto This is exactly what I'm doing, I'm loading both nib file to switch between 2 different views. ps. Il miglior nick su stack overflow

Comment: tnx ;) hope the solution I suggest below fit your needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loading several nibs is of course possible, but you need to make sure your bindings are right in both nib files. If the nib files are simply containing views, make an IBOutlet for each NSView and separate the nibs that way.

Comment: Im actually having issues with the ArrayController (i've linked my outlet mainArrayController to the ArrayController component in both nib files). And I need it in both files.

Comment: They will probably overwrite. Why do you need the outlet to the arraycontroller? Can't you make 1 nib file and do everything there?

Comment: I have a multiple targets app. Most of the nib components are the same for all apps, but one specific panel is specific for each target. I would like to separate such panel in several nib files loaded by each app.

Comment: I'm trying now with 2 different arrayControllers and the following line, but I get a EXC_BAD_ACCESS: [mainArrayController bind:@"contentArray" toObject:seriesArrayController withKeyPath:@"arrangedObjects" options:nil];

Comment: Just a question : do you need to do everything in the nibs, or can't you bind the array controller programmatically? If you can post your project somewhere (like on mediafire) that'd be handy, if not, it's kinda hard to help you out.

Comment: Ok. I can't post it, too big. But I don't understand your answer: what is going to change if I bind the array controller programmatically ? Why is it better ?

Comment: I don't understand your above call though. Are you binding an arraycontroller to an arraycontroller? Did you try debugging the whole thing?

Answer (score 0):

Try this way: create a main view for the viewcontroller, the size you need it and empty. Then create a new class derived from UIView (i.e.: AlternativeView) and set the view class in your XIBs as this new class.
In the AlternativeView.m put a method like this:

```
+ (id) newAlternativeView:(NSString*)nibName{
  NSArray* nibViews =  [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:nibName owner:self options:nil];
  AlternativeView *me = [nibViews objectAtIndex: 0];
  return me;
}
```

Now you can create your view by using +(id)newAlternativeView:(NSString*)nibName and add/remove them to the main view of the viewcontroller. In this way you can even compose the view with many subviews loaded by different xib.

Comment: maybe is not exactly what you are looking for, but this solution have lots of upside, 'cause  you can mix different views form different xib

Comment: By loading multiple nib files, I encounter the problem to share my main array controller with all of them. (They all have similar fields, and few specific fields). When I link the array controller to a nib, the connection is lost for the previous one.